# Is there a way to get the last push notification when my app starts up?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In the scenario where a user did not swipe a push notification before it disappeared, is there any way to retrieve the last one sent to the device for my app? I can go into the notification center and see the last few push notifications for my app there, is there any way I can retrieve the last one when my app opens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve past push notifications.

Typically, this isn't needed. Once launched, your app can communicate with your server to see what's new.

- If the app is launched from a notification, your app will receive the push notification passed in as an option with the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` to the app delegate method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
- If your app is running and in the foreground when the push notification arrives, the app delegate `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be called
- With iOS 7 and later, if the notification type is `content-available` and you have the Background App Refresh capability turned on (and the user has not disabled Background App Refresh), then an app in the background will also get `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification`